# mysql item sales

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

i would like to ask a question here... let me explain it...
here i have 3 table,
1. transaction_table
2. transaction_detail
3. item

Nah, my problem here is i want to know the item sales of this month (2013-01) for an example, here's my table structure...

1 Transaction Table

```
--------------------------
idTransaction | date       | idUser | idCustomer  | total   | NOSC
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1             | 2013-01-01 | 3      | 4           | 500000  | 1CO
2             | 2013-01-01 | 3      | 5           | 450000  | 2CO
3             | 2013-01-01 | 3      | 6           | 250000  | 3CO
```

2 transaction_detail

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
idTransaction | idItem | qty | price
----------------------------------------
1             | 1      | 2   | 250000
2             | 2      | 1   | 250000
2             | 3      | 1   | 200000
3             | 1      | 1   | 250000
```

3 Item Table

```
idItem | Name Item
---------------------------------------
1      | glass
2      | Medicine A
3      | Medicine B
```

4 Customer

```
 idCustomer | Name Customer
    --------------------------------------
    4             | Abuh
    5             | Abeh
    6             | ABooh
```

So based on these table i would like to get data like this....

```
Name Item | Nosc | Customer | Sold Quantity | @ Price | Total
---------------------------------------------
Glass     | 1CO  | Abuh     |2              | 250000  | 500000
Glass     | 3CO  | ABooh    |1              | 250000  | 250000
Medicine A| 2CO  | Abeh     |1              | 250000  | 250000
Medicine B| 2CO  | Abeh     |1              | 200000  | 200000
```

Anyone can help me??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.`name Item`,
        a.qty `Sold Quantity`,
        a.price `@ price`,
        (a.qty * a.price) Total
FROM    transaction_detail a    
        INNER JOIN Item b
            ON a.idItem = b.idItem
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7090/2)

The query above is based on the records and result given on the example. *Follow-up question(s): is there any possibility that a certain Item can be sold with different price? If so, how do you calculate it?*

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  b.`name Item`,
        SUM(a.qty) `Sold Quantity`,
        a.price `@ price`,
        (SUM(a.qty) * a.price) Total,
        c.Date
FROM    transaction_detail a    
        INNER JOIN Item b
            ON a.idItem = b.idItem
        INNER JOIN `transaction` c
            ON a.idtransaction = c.idTransaction
GROUP   BY b.idItem, b.`name Item`, a.price, c.Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab120/4)

**UPDATE 2**

```
SELECT  b.`name Item`,
        SUM(a.qty) `Sold Quantity`,
        a.price `@ price`,
        (SUM(a.qty) * a.price) Total,
        d.`Name Customer`
FROM    transaction_detail a    
        INNER JOIN Item b
            ON a.idItem = b.idItem
        INNER JOIN `transaction` c
            ON a.idtransaction = c.idTransaction
        INNER JOIN Customer d
            ON d.idCustomer = c.idCustomer
GROUP   BY b.idItem, b.`name Item`, a.price, 
           MONTH(c.Date), YEAR(c.Date), d.`Name Customer`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d648/2)

Comment: i need to use the date from transaction table.. how the query is?

Comment: @WawanBrutalx you need to join `Transaction` table. [**>>CLICK_HERE<<**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7090/5)

Comment: how about my follow-up question?

Comment: let me try it first.. wait

Comment: i edit my question, please look... how to group the item to become 1 row??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23882/discussion-between-wawan-brutalx-and-jw)

Answer (score 1):

```
select it.item_name,td.qty,td.price,t.total 
  from transaction as t,transaction_detail as td,item_table as it 
  where t.idTransaction=td.idTransaction 
    and td.idItem=it.idItem 
    and t.date between 'YEAR(CURDATE())."-".MONTH(CURDATE())."-"."01"' 
                   and 'YEAR(CURDATE())."-".MONTH(CURDATE())."-"."31"'
```